# JasperReports: How to remove new page blank in subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have create one report and put subreport into summary. I have problem to remove the new page blank in subreport because i have put clicks "run to bottom" in subreport's properties. After that, i run my report properly. The data appear correctly but problem comes when one new page blank appear after page. I don't know how to remove the blank page. Anyone know about this?

Comment: You should post the screenshot of your resulting report and jrxml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know my mistakes is not put sub report by size band. Size band and sub ​​report must be the same size so that no blank page will come out.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this adding the attribute *isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"* for the *reportElement* tag:

```
<reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" ...
```

And the band height, reportElement height and the subreport height must be equals:

```
<detail>
        <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="60" ...
```